# TouchPad Error while reading pin 2 of esp32

Tags: esp32, micropython

I have installed **micropython** on **ESP32** controller. I read pin 2 using below code

```
from machine import TouchPad, Pin
from time import sleep

def observe_pin(pin_id, d=100):
    i = 0
    t = TouchPad(Pin(pin_id))
    while i < d:
        print("{0} -> {1}".format(pin_id,t.read()))
        sleep(0.5)
        i = i + 1
```

If I read pin 4, it works fine.

```
observe_pin(4)
```

But If I try to read pin 2,

```
observe_pin(2)
```

it gives below error

```
ValueError: Touch pad error
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the on board led as well. Perhaps you are using it somewhere else?
Or perhaps pin 2 was not defined as input - share the whole code.

Comment: it depend on board, is onboard led on Pin 2.

Comment: @YigalB, Above is the only code. I Edited my question to show how I call the function.

Comment: I am not familiar with micropython , yet I believe you need to define the IOs as inputs (or outputs) - something like: p_out = Pin('GP2', mode=Pin.OUT) . By default, GPIOs are set to input, yet it is a good practice to define them actively. I assume pin 2 is set to output because of the led activity.  Did you define the pin to be input?